# degryuter template : forest trees and langsci-avm matrixes do not display

Tags: forest, trees, linguistics

I am having some issues with the degruyter latex template for articles. Everything works, except for syntactic trees and lfg AVMs. I am compiling with xelatex and I am using the forest and langsci-avm with *linguistics* and *lfg* as options respectively. Could someone please help me? Thanks. Here is the minimal code.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\RequirePackage[no-math]{fontspec}[2017/03/31]%(only for the luatex or the xetex engine)
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}
\usepackage[small]{dgruyter}
% get packages from local sty-file
\usepackage{packages}

% Note: A different font will be used in the final version
%\usepackage{times}
% Names for Tables, Figures
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand\tablename{Table}
}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand\figurename{Figure}
}

% We use todonotes for margin notes

\newcommand{\jdg}[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\normalfont#1\ignorespaces}}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{finalcompile}

% Please set finalcompile to true for the final version, to false otherwise

\setboolean{finalcompile}{true}
%\setboolean{finalcompile}{false}

\ifthenelse{\boolean{finalcompile}}{
\usepackage[disable]{todonotes}
\usepackage[final]{showlabels}
}{
\usepackage{todonotes}
\newcommand{\todonote}[2][]{\tikzexternaldisable\todo[#1]{#2}\tikzexternalenable} %needed for externalization
\usepackage[right]{showlabels}
\paperwidth=\dimexpr \paperwidth + 6cm\relax
\marginparwidth=\dimexpr \marginparwidth + 6cm\relax
%\makeatletter 
%\@mparswitchfalse
%\makeatother
%\normalmarginpar
%\reversemarginpar
}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage[lfg]{langsci-avm}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\avmdefinestyle{plain}{attributes=\scshape,
values=\scshape,
types=\normalfont}


\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
[IP[DP][I']]
\end{forest}


\avm[style=plain]{
[pred & `silue']}


\end{document}
```

Here is the error message:

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\bottomrule ->\noalign
{\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@aboverulesep =\aboverulesep \global...
l.67 \end{forest}
I expect to see \noalign only after the \cr of
an alignment. Proceed, and I'll ignore this case.
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
}
l.67 \end{forest}
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text>
\endgroup
l.67 \end{forest}
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
```

Comment: The document class is missing. Also `dgruyter` is not on CTAN and a pointer would be needed.

Comment: And there is a package called `packages` which we don't have either.

Comment: Here is the link of the template : https://www.degruyter.com/publication/journal_key/LING/downloadAsset/LING_TemplateLinguistics.zip

Comment: Yes, Thanks. Alan Munn's link actually answers the first part of the issue, that is for drawing trees. But for the AVMs, I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: For the AVM issue, use `\pretocmd{\avm}{\baretabulars}{}{\fail}`, after loading `langsci-avm`.  Same technique, but since the `langsci-avm` package doesn't use an environment, we need to patch the command rather than add to the environment.

Comment: Great ! That works ! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SiluéLacina I've added an answer since the question isn't a complete duplicate. For future questions, please make your examples as minimal as possible so that people can help you more efficiently.

Comment: Understood. Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DeGruyter package redefines all tabulars to be `booktabs` tabulars, which screws up an package which uses regular tabular environments internally. Luckily they have also provided a way to undo the change, so for any environment like `forest` which causes this error you can use:

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{forest}{\baretabulars}
```

In the case of `langsci-avm` the `\avm` command is a macro rather than an environment, so you can patch the command using `\pretocmd` from `etoolbox`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\avm}{\baretabulars}{}{\fail}
```

If the patching fails because of how the particular command you're trying to patch is defined, the `\fail` macro will return an undefined control sequence error, in which case you'll need to find another way to patch that particular command.

Here's a minimal working example (and this is what your non-working example should have looked like).

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\RequirePackage[no-math]{fontspec}[2017/03/31]%(only for the luatex or the xetex engine)
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[small]{dgruyter}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\AtBeginEnvironment{forest}{\baretabulars}
\usepackage[lfg]{langsci-avm}
\pretocmd{\avm}{\baretabulars}{}{\fail}
\avmdefinestyle{plain}{attributes=\scshape,
values=\scshape,
types=\normalfont}


\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
[IP[DP][I']]
\end{forest}


\avm[style=plain]{
[pred & `silue']}


\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]